# Python - Finding optimal single character wildcard combinations

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, combinatorics

I have two lists of account numbers.

Each element in the lists follows a strict format `XX-XXXX`.

The first list contains ~75k account numbers. I have an ML model that classifies these account numbers and will return ~30k which it is most confident about.

My customers' preferred usage is to use `SQL` single character wildcards `?` to quickly select a list of account numbers that follow the previously mentioned rigid format `XX-XXXX`.

These account numbers can be any *alphanumeric* character. There are 37<sup>n</sup> possible sets of wildcard usages (including the `?`), where `n` is the number of digits in the account number.

I am able to identify the number of unique values that each digit has to help reduce the number of wildcard sets to care about via the following code

```py
>>> account_nums = ['00-4203','10-7370','10-7410']
>>> np_account_nums = np.array([list(i) for i in account_nums]) # Create array of the elements
>>> col_val_counts = [len(np.unique(i,return_counts=True)[0]) for i in np_nums.T]
>>> col_val_counts
[2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2]
```

**What I need** is to use these digit counts to find wildcard sets (can be multiple `?` characters in the string) that are the most likely to represent an appropriate proportion of the list of account numbers.

Answers to the following questions will be the most helpful to me:

1. What is the proportion of the full list of account numbers that are represented by a wildcard set?
2. What is the proportion of that wildcard set that is covered by my predictions.

Ideal output would be similar to this:

```py
>>> account_nums = ['00-4203','10-7370','10-7410']
>>> preds = ['10-7370','10-7410']


desired_output = [
    {'wildcard_set':'?0-????','perc_accounts':'1.00','perc_preds':'0.66'},
    {'wildcard_set':'10-7???','perc_accounts':'0.66','perc_preds':'1.00'},
    .
    .
    .
    {'wildcard_set':'10-73?0','perc_accounts':'0.33','perc_preds':'1.00'}
]
```

I will use these percentages to identify which wildcard sets I should return from the model.

Comment: I'm doubt if using `numpy` helps you.  Processing a list of strings is probably as fast.  `numpy` does not have any special string processing code.

Comment: Thanks @hpaulj, it was more about taking advantage of the count unique function on the transpose than avoiding a list of lists.

Comment: How is the last `perc_pred = 1.00`? Shouldn't it be `0.5`?

Comment: Maybe my question has some ambiguity (and I'm already aware it's too specific :) ). The percentage I am hoping for with `perc_preds` is the percentage of that given wildcard set, `'10-73?0'` in this case, that exists in the list of account numbers that is covered by my predictions, so I still believe `1.00` to be the correct number.

Comment: How do you select wildcard sets? If given two different wilcard sets how do you select the better one?

Comment: @tstanisl, That is mostly the nature of the question. I am hoping to use the two percentages to find the balance (situation dependent) to determine which wildcard sets are worth using. I'm editing the question to reflect this, thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Ok. So you need a minimal set if wildcards that will accept ['10-7370','10-7410'] and not accept ['00-4203']. I think that {'1?-????'} will get the job done, won't it? Do you want to minimize a number of '?' as well?

Comment: @tstanisl yes, there are about 70k account numbers so naturally I want to focus just on the wild card sets that represent my 70k accounts instead of all 35^n possibilities. I'm struggling to find an efficient way to do that. Sorry for the delay.